# How should I configure Travis-Ci for Discord Bot

Tags: travis-ci, discord.js

I wish to test my Discord bot on Travis-Ci, however, I don't know how I should configure it to test my bot, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI can be a little annoying to set for discord bots:

- Create a user account as you created the bot account (without turning it into a bot)
- Log into that account in the same way you do with the bot
- Make the account send messages in some test channel or guild while the bot is running in another instance
- Use the message the bot sends back with your CI library to determine if the bot is working

Comment: So you're saying create a user account with a bot that sends commands and looks at the return messages?

Comment: Yep, for me it's the best way to test a bot since you see it from the user's perspective